# Resharper showing lines for brackets mapping

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

Is there any way to remove these lines. This is kind of distracting and irritating.
[image]

Comment: Do you need to stop code collapsing at all, or just remove these lines only?

Comment: Have you looked in the settings for resharper

Comment: @IIya I wanted to remove these lines only.

Comment: @Mike  of course I did, but did n't find any way to get rid of this.

Answer (score 4):

These lines aren't from ReSharper. I think they're an option in the Productivity Power Tools.

Comment: Thanks alot. Yes I have installed both resharper and PPT, so did not figure out its because of PPT.